# Shortest Common Superstring algorithm?

Tags: string, algorithm, sequence

I'm trying to code this problem here:
[image]

but I'd like to find an algorithm that breaks down the steps for solving the problem. I can't seem to find anything too useful online so I've come here to ask if anyone knows of a resource which I can use to refer to an algorithm that solves this problem.

Comment: In the example how is a subsequence of c?

Comment: @AbhishekBansal - `a` is a subsequence of `c` because the `c` contains the elements of `a` in the order in which they occur in `a`. The elements do not have to be contiguous, just in the same order.

Comment: Edit: This is the shortest common supersequence problem not the shortest common superstring. The shortest common superstring involves finding the maximal overlap between two strings and then merging them.

Answer (score 6):

This is called the [shortest common supersequence problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_common_supersequence). The idea is that in order for the supersequence to be the shortest, we want to find as many shared bits of a and b as possible. We can solve the problem in two steps:

1. Find the longest common subsequence of a and b.
2. Insert the remaining bits of a and b while preserving the order of these bits.

We can solve the [longest common subsequence problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) using dynamic programming.

Comment: All that is required is the length of the shortest common supersequence. I wonder if computing the length requires as much work as finding the actual shortest common supersequence (which is an NP-complete problem--see _Theor. Comp. Sci._, 16(1981), 187-198). If it does, then OP's challenge of finding "an efficient algorithm" is an impossible task.

Comment: @TedHopp No, it is not NP-hard to find the SCS of two sequences. It is only NP-hard to find the SCS of an arbitrary number of sequences :)

Comment: I try to sole the same problem, can you explain more about how to "Insert the remaining bits"? Thank you! @TerryLi

Comment: It's still NP-hard, it's just that 2! and 3! are not very interesting numbers.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Terry Li: it is only NP-complete to find the SCS of multiple sequences. For 2 sequences (say s is of length n and t is of length m), my solution (doesn't use LCS but uses something similar) is done in O(nm) time:

1) Run a global alignment, in which you disallow mismatches, don't penalize indels, and give a positive score to matches (I did +1 for matches, -10 for mismatches, and 0 for indels, but these can be adjusted). (This is O(nm))

2) Iterate over the global alignment for both output strings v and w. If v[i] isn't a gap, output it. Otherwise, output w[i]. (This is O(n+m)).