# Shortest string that contains several by brute force

Tags: python, python-itertools, brute-force

So im trying to solve this exercise by brute force:
I get a random number of random strings and im supposed to find the length of the shortest string that
contains all the strings received.

Example:
ana
ama
nao

Answer: 6  (shortest string is 'amanao')
The code below solves my problem, but not as fast as I want because if i test with a few more strings (or bigger ones) the program takes forever to end.
How can i improve this?

```
    def parse(arg):
        strings=set()
        superS=list()
        for line in arg:
            strings.add(str(line))
            superS.append(line)
        superS=''.join(superS)
        return superS ,strings

    def unique_permutations(iterable, r=None):
        previous = tuple()
        for p in itertools.permutations(sorted(iterable), r):
            if p > previous:
                previous = p
                yield p


    def answer(superS,strings):
        for i in xrange(1,len(superS)+1):
            for elem in unique_permutations(superS, i):
                flag = 1
                tt=''.join(elem)
                for j in strings:
                    if j not in tt:
                        flag=0
                        break
                if flag:
                    return len(tt)

    rd=sys.stdin.read().splitlines()
    a,b=parse(rd)
    print answer(a,b)
```

Comment: This is the "shortest common superstring" problem.  That search term should lead you to lots of discussion and sample code.

Comment: @jasonharper I tried to do some searches but wasn't very successful bc of not knowing what to search for. Thank you !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shortest Common Superstring algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19508095/shortest-common-superstring-algorithm)